# Internet Explorer / MS Edge browser issue traversing xml data

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to traverse a piece of XML to pull some logic rules for a web app. I have managed to get my JavaScript to work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari but am getting console errors in MS browsers stating '**Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference**'.

I am unable to get the solution through trial and error as the error appears early into the code.

Sample of my Javascript;

```
function conditionTrigger(id, callType) {
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlLogic = parser.parseFromString(configXML, "text/xml"),
    tags = xmlLogic.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    conditionsPassed = 0,
    callType;
    if (id.length >= 3) {
        id = id.slice(3);
    }
    console.log(tags[0]);
    console.log(tags[0].children.length);
    console.log('ID to be checked against = ' + id);
    console.log(tags.length + ' nodes.');
    console.log(tags[0].children.length + ' level 1 node children.');
    for(var i01 = 0; i01 < tags[0].children.length; i01++ ){
        console.log(tags[0].children[i01]);
        if (tags[0].children[i01].nodeName == "Rules"){
        console.log(tags[0].children[i01].children.length + ' child nodes of ' +tags[0].children[i01].nodeName + '.');
        for(var i02 = 0; i02 < tags[0].children[i01].children.length; i02++){
            console.log(tags[0].children[i01].children[i02]);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

My xml is below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<output brand="[BRANDNAME]" title="[SCRIPTNAME]" version ="[SCRIPTVERSION]">
<Rules>
 <block id="1000000" triggerID="14">
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Test for something else" setIndex="2">
   <Conditions>
    <Condition type="DataField"  fieldID="6" value="xxx" />
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="DisplayAlert" message="can't move on, xxx found"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Check if forename is 'test' and call is a callback" setIndex="1">
   <Conditions>
    <Condition type="DataField"  fieldID="6" value="test" />
    <Condition type="Callback" />
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="MoveToPanel" panelID="27"/>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="DisplayAlert" message="Aha, this is a callback!"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Default" setIndex="0">
   <Conditions>
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="MoveToPanel" panelID="17"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
 </block>
 <block id="1000001" triggerID="19">
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Default" setIndex="0">
   <Conditions>
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="MoveToPanel" panelID="18"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
 </block>
 <block id="1000002" triggerID="20">
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Default" setIndex="0">
   <Conditions>
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="MoveToPanel" panelID="10"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
 </block>
 <block id="1000003" triggerID="22">
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Default" setIndex="0">
   <Conditions>
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="MoveToPanel" panelID="10"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
 </block>
 <block id="1000004" triggerID="23">
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Default" setIndex="0">
   <Conditions>
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="MoveToPanel" panelID="17"/>
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
 </block>
</Rules>
</output>
```

Comment: Can you identify the elements you are looking for in your XML? Starting with `getElementsByTagName('*')` seems like a strange way to access data as it selects all elements. And if you want the root element which you then seem to try to access with `tags[0]` I would simply use `xmlLogic.documentElement`. From then on I am not sure which elements you want to access but I am sure that `querySelector(All)` and `getElementsByTagName` allow you to name the type of elements you want.

Comment: Also, Stackoverflow allows you to insert your HTML and Javascript snippets in an executable, testable way, consider to insert a snippet in your question we can check and test in IE or Edge to identify the problem.

Comment: The elements will vary as the xml is carrying configuration for a web application - basically in this case a user clicking a button will pass in an ID and the JS needs to traverse the xml to find out what conditions and actions relate to that id, then execute the one with the highest setIndex value if all conditions are met , if no condition set is met the defsult (setIndex = 0) will be triggered and its associated actiobs will fire

Answer (score 0):

I found that by changing .children to .childNodes and getAttribute to use jquery.attr the issue was resolved